# Basics of MongoDB Scripts - How to

Tags: mongodb, nosql

What are the basics of MongoDB Scripts?

I think the script will end with `.js`, and we run it using `mongo try.js`

But if I put

```
print(db.foo.find())
```

in `try.js` and use `mongo try.js`

it will say

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.1
connecting to: test
DBQuery: test.foo -> undefined
```

and if I use the interactive shell by typing `mongo` and type

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c7a73428261000000003a7e"), "a" : 1 }
> print(db.foo.find())
DBQuery: test.foo -> undefined
```

the `{a : 1}` was something I inserted earlier using `db.foo.insert({a:1})`

what are the proper ways of doing MongoDB Scripts and how to print things out like a Ruby `irb` or Python's `IDLE`?  thanks.  (Ruby's `puts a.inspect` or `p a` can both print out the whole structure of `a` usually (all the variable names and values in `a`))

`alert(db.foo.find())` and `console.log(db.foo.find())` won't work either.

Comment: I found that I can print things out using `printjson({hm:'yeah'})`

or `db.foo.find().forEach(printjson)` if not in the shell

Comment: Although already indirectly stated below: An important lesson for me was that piping a file into MongoDB, e.g. `mongo < script.txt` allows to use MongoDB-shell commands, and is different from `mongo script.js`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The external script files are executed outside of the shell context.

The `db.foo.find()` database command only returns a cursor; it **doesn't print anything** by itself. When the command is issued from the shell, the shell will iterate the cursor and print the results. When the command is run from an external script file, nothing is printed.

The `print()` command will print out the string representation of the object. In your case, it's the cursor:

```
> print(db.foo.find())
DBQuery: test.foo -> undefined
```

If you need to print results of the query, you'll have to iterate the cursor in your script file and print each result, similarly to what the shell does:

```
function printResult (r) {
  print(tojson(r))
}

db.foo.find().forEach(printResult)
```

Answer (score 15):

There's a built-in function for printing a json object.

Just append `.forEach(printjson)` to the end of the function call.

```
db.foo.find().forEach(printjson);
```

Answer (score 1):

linux or mac shell:

```
user@comp:$ mongo < script.js
```