# Mongo shell execute query from file and show result

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

How to execute external file using mongo shell and see the result in console?

I have external file, like `query.js` and I would like to execute it and see the result in cmd.

Let's say, content of the file is:

```
db.users.find()
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Put this into your `query.js` file:

```
function get_results (result) {
    print(tojson(result));
}

db.col.find().forEach(get_results)
```

and run:

```
mongo db_name query.js
```

Here's a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595265/basics-of-mongodb-scripts-how-to) why you should do it this way.

Comment: If you want to pipe it to tools like `jq`, you may need to suppress mongo's logs with `--quiet` to avoid parsing errors, e.g. `mongo --quiet db_name query.js | jq -c '.'`

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way I found of running mongodb queries from a file and seeing the output in the console is this:

`query.js`:

```
use my_db;
db.my_collection.findOne()
```

On the command line:
`mongo <query.js`

This displays all the output to the console, as if you were running the queries in the mongo shell individually.

Answer (score 7):

Good information here - wanted to point out that mongo provides a printjson() function so there is no need to write your own unless you need more functionality than printjson() provides.

Example Mongo file (test.js)

```
// Pretty print all documents in test.scratch
use test
db.scratch.find().forEach(printjson)
```

Command

```
mongo < test.js
```

If you want to omit `use test` from the mongo file, perhaps to remove IDE error indications for js files, you can specify the target db on the command line:

```
mongo test < test.js
```

Interesting to note: the above examples use a redirect to push the file into the mongo shell. This calling convention allows you to enter commands just as you would in the shell; including mongo shell convenience commands like `use test`.

Mongo provides another script calling convention: `mongo test test.js` which omits the redirect operator. This calling convention requires `test.js` to be proper javascript and cannot use the mongo shell convenience methods like `use test`; one would use the javascript equivalents like `getSiblingDB()`.

Comment: The accepted answer prints the results to the console.

Comment: Thanks @TheCrazyProgrammer, can't believe I missed that. Update the answer to focus on the built-in `printjson` function and differences in calling conventions.

Answer (score 2):

One thing other answers didn't mention is that `use db` command won't work in external script. The best way is to use `getSiblingDB`, for example, if I want to use database called `my_db`:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB("my_db");

function get_results (result) {
    print(tojson(result));
}

db.col.find().forEach(get_results)
```

Then everything works as you would expect. See [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/).

Comment: Redirecting a file into the mongo shell allows using mongo shell commands.

Comment: Yeah it depends on whether you use `mongo query.js` or `mongo < query.js`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed at some point in the mongo cli, I had to execute the following command to get it to run a file against the database (with mongo cli version 3.4.9)

```
mongo mongodb://192.168.1.1/YourDataBase scriptFile.js
```

Then replace `192.168.1.1` with the ip / hostname of your db, `YourDataBase` with the database name and point to an existing file